# What are the units in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ in general?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What are the units in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ ($n$ is any positive integer) in general? I figured it should a group under multiplication mod $n$, but was wondering if there is any more specific way to represent it?

Comment: one general fact is that an unit cannot be a zero divisor. Then we expect that $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ for $m \in Z_n$.

Comment: $m$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ if and only if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.  To prove this solve Bézout’s equation $am+bn=1$.

Answer (score 2):

The group of units $U_{n}$, of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, consists exactly of those equivalence classes $\overline{m}\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $gcd(m,n)=1$ i.e. the equivalence classes of the integers $m<n$ which are relatively prime to $n$.

You should note, that the cardinality of  $U_{n}$ is $\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler function.